# Create a titleize method, that excludes "little words".

Tags: ruby

I'm making a method to capitalize my input, except any words such as a, an, and...etc.

```
def titleize(string_to_titleize)
    string_to_titleize.split(' ').map { |words| words.capitalize }.join(' ')
end
```

I understand there are gems to do this. I can't grasp how to do it manually. I assume to create a list of words not to be capitalized. Then, exlude them someone.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117340/using-title-case-with-ruby-1-8-7/13117575#13117575

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr = ['a', 'an', 'the']
str ="This is a salil gaikwad working as an engineer"
str.gsub(/\w+/) {|match| arr.include?(match) ? match : match.capitalize} 
#Gives o/p :- This Is a Salil Gaikwad Working As an Engineer
```