# Simon Says game capitalizing words except little words

Tags: ruby, nlp

I am working on a simon_says exercise. I need to get the tests to pass but cannot get the last one to pass. It is supposed to capitalize all the first letters of words passed as a parameter to the titleize method.

My initial instinct was to skip capitalization of all words under 4 characters but this doesn't seem to work as length is not a determining factor(some 3 letters words are supposed to be capitalized and some not, same with 4 letter words).

What is the distinction between a little word and a non-little word here?

This is my error message:

```
  1) Simon says titleize does capitalize 'little words' at the start of a title
     Failure/Error: titleize("the bridge over the river kwai").should == "The Br
idge over the River Kwai"
       expected: "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
            got: "The Bridge Over The River Kwai" (using ==)
     # ./03_simon_says/simon_says_spec.rb:92:in `block (3 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

Finished in 0.01401 seconds
15 examples, 1 failure
```

This is my code thus far:

```
def titleize(t)
q = t.split(" ")
u = []

    if q.length == 1
        p = t.split("")
        p[0] = p[0].upcase
        r = p.join("")
        return r
    else q.each do |i|
            if i == "and"
                u.push(i)
            else
            p = i.split("")
            p[0] = p[0].upcase
            r = p.join("")
            u.push(r)
            end
        end
    s = u.join(" ")
    return s
    end
end
```

Comment: You could just create an array of all "little words" like `['over','the']` and then always upcase the first word, irrespective of size.

Comment: Here's a similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813874/create-a-titleize-method-that-excludes-little-words?rq=1

Comment: But the exercise does not give any indication of what are considered little words or else I would have done this method as well.. I am guessing they want something more. If this was what they wanted then they would have explicitly stated which are the little words..

Comment: Checkout this [site](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html) which gives you the exact rules for capitalisation.  Looks like 'over' is a preposition so it doesn't get capitalised.  So maybe get a big list of prepositions going?  Maybe the [engtagger](https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger) gem?

Comment: Yeah I ended up just making a list of small words enough to pass the tests.

Comment: I'm guessing your professor would like for you to compile a list and think about what kinds of words ended up in the list. Hint: [closed classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_class) (but not all closed classes)