# Converting string to title-case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I'm a bit of a noob in Ruby and my mission is to manually convert a string into title-case. I have finally been able to create a method that I believe will meet the requirements for my assignments (it's not very flexible, but it will do), however I have hit one final snag. I cannot seem to join the final array into one string. My code and Rspec errors are below. I believe I have to use the .join(" ") somewhere, but I am not sure of the exact syntax. Thanks in advance for the help!

My code:

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def fix
    string.split(" ").each_with_index do |value, index|
      if index >= 2 && value.length <= 3
        value.downcase!
      else
        value.capitalize!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec:

```
expected: "The Great Gatsby"
     got: ["The", "Great", "Gatsby"]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

again:

```
expected: "Little Red Riding Hood"
     got: ["Little", "Red", "Riding", "Hood"]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

again:

```
expected: "The Lord of the Rings"
     got: ["The", "Lord", "of", "the", "Rings"]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

again:

```
expected: "The Sword and the Stone"
     got: ["The", "Sword", "and", "the", "Stone"]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3):

quick fix:

```
  def fix
    string.split(" ").each_with_index do |value, index|
      if index >= 2 && value.length <= 3
        value.downcase!
      else
        value.capitalize!
      end
      value
    end.join(" ")
  end
```

If you want the ruby way of doing it:

```
def fix
  string.split(" ").map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I implement the first solution (by adding .join(" ") rspec gives me the following error `exercise.rb:17:in <top (required)>': undefined method join' for :fix:Symbol (NoMethodError)
 from exercise_spec.rb:2:in 'require'
 from exercise_spec.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'`

Comment: here was my code all together: `class Title
  attr_accessor :string
  
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end
  
  def fix
    string.split(' ').each_with_index do |value, index|
      if index >= 2 && value.length <= 3
        value.downcase!
      else
        value.capitalize!
      end
    end
  end
end.join(" ")`

Comment: Nvm, I was able to add the `end.join(' ')` closing out the if/else statement and that did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: fixed code. seems the join was on the method and return was not string. guess I did not pay attention enough. should work now

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport provides a method called `titleize` that does what you're describing:

```
>> "the great gatsby".titleize
=> "The Great Gatsby"
>> "little red riding hood".titleize
=> "Little Red Riding Hood"
>> "the lord of the rings".titleize
=> "The Lord Of The Rings"
```

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the "manual" requirement, and it capitalizes words <= 3 characters long, which the OP didn't want to do.

Comment: I guess you _could_ reinvent the wheel every time you want to go to town, but why?

Comment: Because the requirements specify it? ActiveSupport's Titleize is close, but doesn't pass the specs.

Comment: To meet that spec it seems like it would be necessary to use an exclusion list. Maybe something like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078964/ruby-titleize-how-do-i-ignore-smaller-words-like-and-the-or-etc

Answer (score 0):

To offer an alternate solution:

```
def fix
  string.downcase.gsub(/^\S+|(\S{4,})/, &:capitalize)
end
```

This simply replaces each word which appears at the beginning of the string or is 4+ characters long with its capitalized version.

Comment: Using that method,  "jo and the big gem job" yields "Jo and the big gem job".

Comment: Obviously not semantically correct in the case of acronyms, but should will be correct for the purpose of the OP's problem as posed. His version would downcase words <= 3 characters long, as well. A comprehensive solution would require stopword lists and even potentially some POS tagging.

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment after you posted... my original test string was "I fly to my private island in HI"